# Compiler Failed using REMIX IDE

Tags: javascript, python, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

Having trouble compile this Smart Contract using Remix IDE, it doesn't seem to want to compile. I tried looking for anything in the language or text that can be causing it but nothing so far.

Error message:

```
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
  --> CloudMan.sol:31:110:
   |
31 |         return string(abi.encodePacked("https://arweave.net/ibSCLjO_4VRQ7Q1DYHuC3chjFR_wpTJr9UuvK_XcRhs/ou", Strings.toString(_tokenId),".json"));
   |                                                                                                              ^^^^^^^
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.3/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.3/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.3/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Supply.sol";


contract Cloud is ERC1155, Ownable, ERC1155Supply {

    uint256 constant SleepyPinkDragon = 1;
    uint256 constant ThickCloud = 2;
    uint256 constant BlackHairPelicanCloud = 3;
    uint256 constant Superhuman = 4;
    uint256 constant Rattle = 5;

    mapping (uint256 => string) private _uris;

    constructor() ERC1155("https://arweave.net/ibSCLjO_4VRQ7Q1DYHuC3chjFR_wpTJr9UuvK_XcRhs/ou.json")
    
    {
        
     _mint(msg.sender, SleepyPinkDragon, 22, "");
     _mint(msg.sender, ThickCloud, 5, "");
     _mint(msg.sender, BlackHairPelicanCloud, 5, "");
     _mint(msg.sender, Superhuman, 3, "");
     _mint(msg.sender, Rattle, 3, "");
    }

function uri(uint256 _tokenId) override public pure returns (string memory){
        return           string(abi.encodePacked("https://arweave.net/ibSCLjO_4VRQ7Q1DYHuC3chjFR_wpTJr9UuvK_XcRhs/ou", Strings.toString(_tokenId),".json"));
    }


    function setURI(string memory newuri) public onlyOwner {
        _setURI(newuri);
    }

    function mint(address account, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes memory data)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        _mint(account, id, amount, data);
    }

    function mintBatch(address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory amounts, bytes memory data)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        _mintBatch(to, ids, amounts, data);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address operator, address from, address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory amounts, bytes memory data)
        internal
        override(ERC1155, ERC1155Supply)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, ids, amounts, data);
    }
}
```

Check for language errors and text errors but not finding any.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to use a string library, but you haven't included it in the contract. You can use the OpenZeppelin String library:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

contract Cloud is ERC1155, Ownable, ERC1155Supply {

using Strings for uint256;
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the **Strings**  you have to import it from openzeppelin. Add this import to your contract to fix this error.

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";